# Display letters in reverse order of stacks

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I wrote this code  of stacks using a linked list but I am having a problem with the code it prints the letters in reverse order without creating a function to display the letters in reverse order

class SimpleLinkedListStack2 implements SimpleStack ,Iterable {

```
static class ListNode<T> {
    public T value;
    public ListNode<T> next;


    public ListNode(T value, ListNode<T> next) {

        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

private ListNode<T> head = null;
private int count = 0;
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<T>() {
        private ListNode<T> next = head;
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return next != null;
        }
        @Override
        public T next() {
            if (next == null)
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            T value = next.value;
            next = next.next;
            return value;
        }
    };
    }




@Override
public void push(T value) {
    head = new ListNode<>(value, head);
    count++;
}

@Override
public T pop() throws Exception {
    if (count == 0) {
        throw new Exception("Stack is empty");
    }
    T value = head.value;
    head = head.next;
    count--;
    return value;
}

@Override
public T peek() throws Exception {
    if (count == 0) {
        throw new Exception("Stack is empty");
    }
    return head.value;
}


}
```

this is the main class

```
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   SimpleLinkedListStack2 <String>stack2= new SimpleLinkedListStack2<>();
   stack2.push("a");
   stack2.push("b");
   stack2.push("c");
   stack2.push("d");
   stack2.push("e");
   for (String letters : stack2){
       System.out.println(letters);
   }



}
}
```

the out but is

e
d
c
b
a
because I need to make a function to display the letters in reverse order in the class SimpleLinkedListStack2

Comment: A stack is a data structure that uses the Last-in-first-out . Your output is entirely expected and if it wouldn't output the last element you put in first, then it wouldn't be a stack.

Answer (score 0):

Just walk through your code:

> `stack2.push("a");`

This changes your stack's `head` from `null` to a node that has no `next` and whose value is `"a"`. Your stack is now: `-> ["a", -> null]`, where `->` is 'pointing at object'.

> `stack2.push("b");`

And now your stack is `-> ["b", -> ["a", -> null]]`: You create a new ListNode object for `"b"`, and update its 'next' pointer to be what head was, and then head points at this newly created thing.

Thus, of course, if you then iterate through it, you get the last thing you added ("b" here), first.

Hence, your code pritns `e d c b a` - it's what you put in the list, in reverse order, because that's what you programmed, and that's what stacks are (they are 'Last in, First Out' - the last thing you put it is the `e`, and that's the first thing that comes out, as per the design!

### But I want to print in the same order I put the items in!

This is a so-called 'singly linked list', meaning, any given LinkedNode knows its next node, but does not know its previous node. **You cannot in-place reverse-walk-through a singly linked list** - what you want is not possible without drastic steps.

For example, you could make an entirely new stack, just by iterating through this stack, which naturally ends up with the newly created stack being the exact reverse of the original. And then print that reversed stack, and then toss it away (java is garbage collected; that part happens automatically). There is no 'easy' solution / no solution that takes no memory. You could also just build the string out, and then reverse that instead.

Perhaps that's the point of this homework exercise, to make you think about how these LinkedNode objects relate to each other in memory. Get out a pad of paper and go sketch it out. Boxes and arrows. You'll figure it out.